# Adding a global method in Javascript.net

Tags: c#, javascript.net

I am working on a project that uses Javascript.net (formerly Noesis Javascript .net) as a scripting engine.

How do you add a C# method to the global context in Javascript?
For example, say I have in C#:

```
public int Foo(int bar)
{
    return bar * 2;
}
```

I want to be able to call in Javascript:

```
var x = 5;
var y = Foo(x); // y is now 10;
```

In other libraries such as Jurassic this is possible:

```
 engine.SetGlobalFunction("Foo", new Func<int, int>((a) => a*2));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example comes from the unit tests:

```
_context.SetParameter("f", new Func<string,string>((s) => s.ToUpper()));
_context.Run("f('Noesis') == 'NOESIS'").Should().BeOfType<bool>().Which.Should().BeTrue();
```

Comment: In my case I wanted to expose a static C# method in the global object. So I used _context.SetParameter("myfunc", new Action<string>(TheFunctionInCSharp)); which worked.